# Dict values compared are not showing to be the same in python

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, dictionary, if-statement

So I have a function which essentially checks if file names are the same are not. I don't understand even though the key names are the same , and the values have been swapped around in a different order , why does it output that files are not the same. If they are in the exact same order then that will work.

I am sure that with dict , order does not matter but in my case it seems that order does. Firstly , i want to be able to print out file name that have a match , and second , i want to be able to print out file names that don't have a match. I have made a start on my code and this is what I have so far :

```
import os
import json

def sort_files():
    """Sort files in ascending order"""
    files = os.listdir('dates/')
    return sorted(files, reverse=True)


def current_day():
    """Get the current day file"""
    return sort_files()[0]


def previous_day():
    """Get the previous day file"""
    return sort_files()[1]


def compare_files():

    with open('dates/' + current_day(), 'r') as current_data_file, open('dates/' + previous_day(),
                                                                        'r') as pre_data_file:

        for current_data, previous_data in zip(current_data_file, pre_data_file):

            data_current = json.loads(current_data)
            data_previous = json.loads(previous_data)
            current_fn = data_current['File Name']
            previous_fn = data_previous['File Name']

            if sorted(previous_fn) == sorted(current_fn):
                print("OK")
                return


            if data_previous != data_current:
                print("Files are not the same")
                return

            else:
                print("Not the same")
```

Comment: A dictionary cannot contain multiple identical keys.

Comment: In your dictionaries, you have assigned two values for the same key and by default, dicts hold the last value for each key. That means that your function compares `yasser.json` with `stats.json` which are different file names. You need to assign each filename to different key if you want both names.

Comment: What if i was comparing two files :

file1.json 

{"File Name": "apa.json", "File Size": 0}
{"File Name": "earningsData.json", "File Size": 2000}

file2.json

{"File Name": "earningsData.json", "File Size": 2000}
{"File Name": "apa.json", "File Size": 0}

Would this still be the same case @VasilisG.

Comment: Your function would return that your files are not the same.

Comment: Even though the order of the data in my json files may not the same , the key names and values are the same. How can I adjust my function in order to deal with that @VasilisG.

Comment: If you could clarify that a bit more in your question, I would be able to help you, because I don't quite understand what do you want to do with that last example you provided in the comments.

Comment: I have just updated the question along with the code @VasilisG.

Comment: Please note that in python 2 and <3.6 dictionaries are not ordered. In case you want them to be ordered, use the [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html)